# Good references for the binary tetrahedral group (2T)

Tags: representation-theory

How can I compute the order of each conjugacy class and how I can write down the character table for the binary tetrahedral group?

Comment: https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~jm/wiki/Representations/BinaryCubic

Comment: Yes I saw these solution and there are 7  conjugacy class but it is not clear to me how they write the character table, please could you  Justify this answer

Comment: Please  show me if there are any one know good references for that ,

Comment: Can you see that the conjugacy classes are (i) the identity, (ii) a central element of order 2 (iii) the 6 elements of order 4 (iv) and (v) 4 of the elements of order 3 (vi) and (vii) 4 of the elements of order 6?

Comment: Do you know that the group modulo its centre is $A_4$ and that therefore gives you 4 rows of the character table. [If you don't know the character table of $A_4$ then work it out first.]

Comment: Can you see that the other three rows must be degree 2 characters? [There's no other way to get the sum of squares of the degrees correct.] Can you see that this, and orthogonality gives the first column and the column on the central involution. Can you see that orthogonality gives that the column on the elements of order 4 then ends in three 0's? After that we need a bit of thought!

Comment: Please Gould you look for the page 40 in this note  (Representation Theory and the McKay
Correspondence
Bachelorthesis)  is this the answer correct